Lambda Function : "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'utils'"
I been trying to upload a Docker image to AWS Lambda Function,
My imports in the Lambda function Look like this:
...
from utils.textarct_ocr_facturas import Textract
from utils.clasificador_doc import clasificadorDoc2S3
from utils.sendDatabase import postgreSQLDatabase
from utils.openai_qr import OpenAIStrucured
...

And my folders like this:
Lambda (folder)
 |_lambda_function.py
 |_Dockerfile
 |_requirements.txt
 |__init_.py
 |_utils (folder)
   |_textarct_ocr_facturas.py
   |_clasificador_doc.py
   |_sendDatabase.py
   |_openai_qr.py

The error is this :
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'utils'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}

I tried to import with ".utils...." but the error is the same.
I don't know whatsgoing on with these modules.
Please help.
Thanks.

How did it go? Is it still unclear what you should do?

__init_.py should be created in utils/ folder. Otherwise, utils is not considered as a module.
